# PCL storage package does not create folder

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have used PCL storage package to create a folder for my application. I referred to [this](https://github.com/dsplaisted/PCLStorage). Here is my code sample:

```
        public ListPage()
        {
            testFile();
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = {
                    new Label { Text = "Hello ContentPage" }
                }
            };
        }

        async public void testFile()
        {
            // get hold of the file system
            IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

            // create a folder, if one does not exist already
            IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("MySubFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

            // create a file, overwriting any existing file
            IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("MyFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            // populate the file with some text
            await file.WriteAllTextAsync("Sample Text...");


        }
```

The folder for files is getting created under sdcard/android/data/ directory but it does not create "MySubFolder" folder under files.

I have set WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for my android project. Am I missing any other configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Having run into similar issues (though on iOS), I now have this working, maybe it helps you. The issues are properly dealing with the async calls and other threading fun.

First, my use case is that I bundle a number of file resources with the app, provided for the user at first run, but from then on updated online. Therefore, I take the bundles resources and copy them into the filesystem proper:

```
var root = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

// already run at least once, don't overwrite what's there
if (root.CheckExistsAsync(TestFolder).Result == ExistenceCheckResult.FolderExists)
{
    _testFolderPath = root.GetFolderAsync(TestFolder).Result;
    return;
}

_testFolderPath = await root.CreateFolderAsync(TestFolder, CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists).ConfigureAwait(false);

foreach (var resource in ResourceList)
{
    var resourceContent = ResourceLoader.GetEmbeddedResourceString(_assembly, resource);
    var outfile = await _testFolderPath.CreateFileAsync(ResourceToFile(resource), CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    await outfile.WriteAllTextAsync(resourceContent);
 }
```

Notice the .ConfigureAwait(false). I learned this from the excellent

[MSDN Best Practises article on async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Before, I was going back and forth between the method NOT creating directories or files - as in your question - or the thread hanging. The article talks about the latter in detail.

The ResourceLoader class is from here:

[Embedded Resource](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/EmbeddedResources)

The ResourceToFile() method is just a helper that turns the long resource names in iOS to shorted file names, as I prefer those. It's not germaine here (IOW: it's a kludge I'm ashamed to show ;)

I think I understand threading better day by day, and if I understand correctly, the art here is to ensure you wait for the async method that load and write files to finish, but make sure you do that on a thread pool that will not deadlock with the main UI thread.