# How can I bundle a xml file with the app and create a file inside a folder

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to bundle a xml file with the app. I would also like to read and write to that file.

I tried this [working-with files](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/) to read and write to a text file but I want to read and write to a xml file.

Also my app has to create a folder for the app which will have another xml file. This file should be accessible by the end user.

I also tried PCL storage ref to my question: [PCL storage does not create folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596519/pcl-storage-package-does-not-create-folder)

How can I bundle a file with the app and create a file and a folder from my app.

Comment: I'm curious what your solution to the problem (including your other question) was? I am literally trying to solve a similar issue as I type this. My current solution approach is that I want to include a number of embedded resources, that only get used at first start of the app. They will then get copied to the main device file system and in the future receive updates online.